# How do I access html file in java code when working with other html file? (using Spring framework)

Tags: java, html, spring

Basically, I want to work on a small website that sells books. Some of the code has been provided, I just need to add some more functions. The one I'm struggling with is the following: When the user has added a book to their shopping bag, I want to display books as a suggestion that were written by the same author. 
I am working on a java file that contains the following class:

```
@PostMapping("/shopping_bag")
String addBook(@RequestParam("id") Book book, @ModelAttribute Shopping_bag bag) { ... }
```

This does exactly what it's supposed to and works perfectly. I'm now using this as a base for my suggestions. So, I'm trying to also access another html file called "library.html" in this class. When this class is being called, I am on the "shopping_bag" website, right before the user adds the book he chose to his shopping bag. I need access to the page "library", so I can go through the books similar to the one he is choosing to find the author. I have no idea how to do that though. I tried this:

```
@PostMapping("/shopping_bag")
@GetMapping("/library")
String addBook(@RequestParam("id") Book book, @ModelAttribute Shopping_bag bag, @ModelAttribute Catalog_Books books) { ... }
```

and several other variations of @something. But all I can get is a new catalog of books and not the actual library. I just can't figure out how to do it since I just started using Spring and am just starting to get how it works.

Comment: You'll probably not get the books from a library html page but use the same code that's used to create that page, e.g. you read the books from a database (assuming you're using one).

Comment: I actually tried that in the beginning but I can't access the class that initializes the library. It's a private class in another package and I got a hint with this task as well. Apparently I have to pass it into my class "addBook" by using the @attribues in the controller.